# Algorithm (or C# library) for identifying 'keywords' in a set of messages?

Tags: c#, algorithm, search, nlp, text-mining

I want to build a list of ~6 keywords (or even better: couple word keyphrases) for each message in a message forum.

- The primary use of keywords is to replace subject lines in some instances. For example: *Message from Terry sent Dec 5, keywords: **norweigan blue, plumage, not dead***
- In a super ideal world keywords would identify both unique phases, and phrases that cluster the discussion into "topics", i.e. words that are highly relevant to the message in question, and a few other messages in the forum, but not found frequently in the forum as a whole.
- I expect junk phrases to show up, no big deal.
- Can't be too computationally expensive: I need something that can handle several hundred messages in several seconds, as I'll need to re-run this every time a new message comes in.

Anyone know a good C# library for accomplishing this? Maybe there's a way to bend Lucene.NET into providing this sort of info?

Or, failing that, can anyone suggest an algorithm (or set of algos) to read up on? If I'm implementing myself I need something not terribly complex, I can only tackle this if its tractable in about a week. Right now, the best I've found in terms of simple-but-effective is [TF-IDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf).

**UPDATE:** I've uploaded the results of using TF-IDF to select the top 5 keywords from a real dataset here: http://jsbin.com/oxanoc/2/edit#preview

The results are mediocre, but not totally useless... maybe with the addition of detecting multi-word phrases, this would be good enough.

Comment: Hmmm, I think what you may need is this: [TAGME project](http://tagme.di.unipi.it/)

Comment: If you want typos like your example to be caught as well, you'll need a spell checker, and your algorithm is going to be computationally expensive!

Comment: I'm ok with typos coming through. My focus is more on "make sure at least a couple really useful keywords appear in the list" rather than "make sure there's nothing dumb in the keyword list".

Comment: I've put keyword output from a naive TF-IDF implementation run across real messages here (message shown on hover): [TF-IDF selected keywords from real data](http://jsbin.com/oxanoc/2/edit#preview). The results are ok, but not stellar. I think they reveal a real need for multi-word phrases.

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented a keywords extraction algorithm in Java a few weeks ago for uni. project, and used the [tf-idf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) model.

**Algorithm:**

First, we looked for all [bigrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigram) in the paragraph, and extracted the meaningful ones. (*)

Next, we took the set of unigrams and bigrams, and evaluated each with is respective tf-idf score. The idf score of each term was the "documents count" retrieved by [Bing API](http://www.bing.com/developers/s/APIBasics.html).

(*) **Deciding which bi-gram is meaningful:**

We used a various heuristics to find which bi-gram can be considered meaningful. At the end, the best results were achieved by "asking" wikipedia: we searched for the bi-gram. If there is an article containing this bi-gram, we considered it meaningful.

**Evaluation:**

We evaluated the algorithm on a set of 50 abstracts from random articles, and extracted the [precision and recall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_%28information_retrieval%29) of these algorithms.

The result was ~40% recall and ~35% precision, which is not too bad.